# Where is my faction city in Pandaria?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have heard that each faction (Alliance/Horde) has their own city or stronghold on Pandaria, which includes portals to every major city (faction cities, race cities, cities from previous expansion) along with trainers, an inn, a bank, etc.

Where can I find my faction city in Pandaria?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The faction cities are located in the Vale of Eternal Blossoms, the Alliance city is called Shrine of Seven Stars and is located in the south east of the zone.

The Horde city is called Shrine of Two Moons and is located on the northern edge of the zone, just west of Mogu'shan Palace.

[image: Vale of Eternal Blossoms map]